# Generic Error Message on Google Maps Autocomplete

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to implement an address autocomplete feature on a site and have copied the exact code from the Google Developer's site example, switching only my API key, but I get a very generic error message when I type anything into my HTML form:

"This page was unable to display a Google Maps element. Please contact the site administrator. If you are the administrator of this site, please check the JavaScript console or check the following page for troubleshooting: http://g.co/mapsJSApiErrors"

Here is the code snippet I am using, which works perfectly on Google's site.  Again, the only thing I have replaced is my API key and the error is not complaining about my key anyway.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Answer (score 0):

This was an error caused by the API not being activated within the Google Dev Console.  I was issued a key so I assumed it was active but there is a separate step to enabled the API this was not expressed in the error message but was discovered using the debugger.